# Meteor JS: How to prevent double rerendering when using Meteor.call to insert into a collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor

**Here is my problem:**

Within an template event handler, I am using `Meteor.call()` to call a method to insert a document into a collection.

For some reason this causes the associated template to render two times instead of one. If I use `Collection.insert()` directly within the event handler, the template renders only once. I'm very confused why it would render twice. How do I prevent the template from rendering twice when the data changes?

**Here is my code:**

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.postItem.rendered = function(e){
    console.log("This was rendered");
  }

  Template.postsList.helpers({
    posts: function() {
      return Posts.find();
    }
  });

  Template.postsList.events({
    'submit form' : function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var post = {
        title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
      }

      // This causes double render
      Meteor.call('post', post, function(error, id){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

      // This causes only a single render
      //Posts.insert(post);
    }
  });
}

Meteor.methods({
  post: function(attrs) {
    return Posts.insert(attrs);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem. You can read [unofficial FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq) about this issue (Why do I sometimes see two copies of a document during a latency compensated method?).

I personally solved this problem by generating id in the method (as a hash of the document being inserted plus a bit of random salt passed as parameter to calm down paranoia) and perform inserts with the same id on client and server.

Comment: Oh boy, that's frustrating. I just tried your suggestion of generating the id ahead of time as part of the hash being sent. It sort of works, until I do things like add a timestamp on the server to the document such as `submit: new Date().getTime()`. Then it will render twice again. What do you mean by `random salt`?

Comment: @Chanpory I mean the following:

1. My method has extra parameter 'randomSeed' (it's optional, btw)
2. Then, after it creates object to insert, it generates id for it by the following line of code:

    var id = Random.create([user._id, text, randomSeed]).id();

3. Then it performs `insert` operation on collection. You can try `upsert` instead - not sure what's the difference
inside method stub.

Comment: @NahuelChaves in the FAQ I referred to there is a link to Meteor's roadmap on Trello, corresponding ticket is market as 'recently completed', despite there are some comments like 'where is documentation'? Does this problem persists on the last version on Meteor (>=1.0)?

Comment: I'm still having this trouble in doyourjob.meteor.com (adding companies) ... https://github.com/nahue/DoYourJob/blob/master/models/companies.js has the method definition

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any github issue or SO answer that tackled this problem so I hacked my own workaround (at least for now):

```
// Insert if recent comment from other user
function _insertComment(){
    let doc = { //.. 
    };

    let commentId = Comments.insert(doc, (error, _id) => {
        if (error) { console.log(error) }
        else { return _id }
    });
    let userId = Meteor.users.update({_id: self.userId}, {$push: {comments: commentId}});
    let pId = Projects.update({_id: projectId}, {$push: {comments: commentId}});

    throw new Meteor.Error('success', 'Sent!');
}

// Update comment content array for same user
function _updateComment(){
    let recentComment = Comments.find({projectId: projectId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch();
    let commentId = Comments.update({_id: recentComment[0]['_id']}, {$push: {content: comment}});
    throw new Meteor.Error('success', 'Sent!');
}
```

I faced this problem because I'm creating a facebook inbox-like comment system. Inside an `'insertComment'` method, I check whether if the user is still commenting without any other user comments before or not, hence the need of checking if the discussion needs to be updated or not.

The trick was to make a `Meteor.Error` that stops everything and sends the error response to the client, but with a 'success' message.

The `Comments` collection is working fine now. It evolved from this:

```
{
        "_id" : "GEtzmDPzDB4Yt2ux5",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-20T22:48:56.488Z"),
        "userId" : "jza5u7SMoKwHMpJwi",
        "projectId" : "on95SYYSjAy5p88Q4",
        "content" : [
            "1er comentario hecho por netpoe",
            "2do comment de netpoe",
            "2do comment de netpoe",
            "4to comment seguido de netpoe",
            "4to comment seguido de netpoe",
            "5to comment de netpoe",
            "5to comment de netpoe",
            "Ya no insertes más a netpoe",
            "Ya no insertes más a netpoe",
            "Ya no insertes más a netpoe",
            "Ya no insertes más a netpoe"
        ]
    }
```

To this

```
{
    "_id" : "7qeRrfTTT5JdTHdL3",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-21T18:33:35.435Z"),
    "userId" : "D3mK7EKSKcvQ9v9bd",
    "projectId" : "joZnWP3CZqwZFhD2C",
    "content" : [
        "Gracias! La neta es que sí me tomó unas cuantas horitas",
        "Pero ya está lista! :D"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "PBF8RfGFeZrx4y4ZD",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-21T18:33:50.790Z"),
    "userId" : "jza5u7SMoKwHMpJwi",
    "projectId" : "joZnWP3CZqwZFhD2C",
    "content" : [
        "Nice! Pues a estrenarla no?"
    ]
}
```